# cuda magma matrix-matrix addition kernel

Tags: c, matrix, cuda, magma

I tried using similar format as  magmablas_sgeadd_q kernel, however I am not getting proper outputs, moreover every time I run it, I get a different output. 
The code that I used is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#define BLK_X 2
#define BLK_Y 1

__global__ void matrixAdd2( const float *dA, const float *dB, float *dC, int m, int n)
{
int ldda = m;
int lddb = m;

int ind = blockIdx.x*BLK_X + threadIdx.x;
int iby = blockIdx.y*BLK_Y;
/* check if full block-column */
bool full = (iby + BLK_Y <= n);
/* do only rows inside matrix */
if ( ind < m ) {
    dA += ind + iby*ldda;
    dB += ind + iby*lddb;
    if ( full ) 
    {
        // full block-column
        #pragma unroll
        for( int j=0; j < BLK_Y; ++j )
        {
            dC[j*lddb] = dA[j*ldda] + dB[j*lddb];
            printf("A is %f, B is %f, C is %f  \n",dA[j*ldda],dB[j*lddb],dC[j*lddb]);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // partial block-column
        for( int j=0; j < BLK_Y && iby+j < n; ++j )
        {
            dC[j*lddb] = dA[j*ldda] + dB[j*lddb];
            printf("parital: A is %f, B is %f, C is %f  \n",dA[j*ldda],dB[j*lddb],dC[j*lddb]);
        }
    }
}
}



int main ( void )
{

int m = 4; // a - mxn matrix
int n = 2; // b - mxn matrix

size_t size =  m * n * sizeof(float);


printf("Matrix addition of %d rows and %d columns \n", m, n);

// allocate matrices on the host

float *h_A = (float *)malloc(size); // a- mxn matrix on the host
float *h_B = (float *)malloc(size); // b- mxn matrix on the host
float *h_C = (float *)malloc(size); // b- mxn matrix on the host


// Initialize the host input matrixs
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n ; j ++)
    {
        h_A[i*m+j] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_B[i*m+j] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;

    }
}

// Allocate the device input matrix A   
float *d_A = NULL;
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size);; // d_a - mxn matrix a on the device

// Allocate the device input matrix B
float *d_B = NULL;
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, size);

// Allocate the device output matrix C
float *d_C = NULL;
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, size);

// Copy the host input matrixs A and B in host memory to the device input    matrixs in device memory
printf("Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device\n");
err = cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

err = cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// defining number of threads and blocks    
dim3 threads( BLK_X, 1 );
dim3 grid((int)ceil(m/BLK_X),(int)ceil(n/BLK_Y) );


// Launching kernel     
matrixAdd2<<<grid, threads, 0>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, m, n);

// Copy the device result matrix in device memory to the host result matrix in host memory.
printf("Copy output data from the CUDA device to the host memory\n");
err = cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

//print A matrix 
printf("Matrix A");
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {
        printf(" %f", h_A[i*m+j]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}

// print B matrix if required
printf("Matrix B");
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {

        printf(" %f", h_B[i*m+j]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}

//Error checkng
printf("Matrix C ");
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
   {    
        printf("%f", h_C[i*m+j]);
        if(h_C[i*m+j] == h_A[i*m+j] + h_B[i*m+j] )
        { 
            flag = flag + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

if(flag==m*n)
{
printf("Test PASSED\n");
}


// Free device global memory
err = cudaFree(d_A);

err = cudaFree(d_B);

err = cudaFree(d_C);

// Free host memory
free(h_A);
free(h_B);
free(h_C);


err = cudaDeviceReset();
printf("Done\n");
return 0;

}
```

Output I got:

Matrix addition of 4 rows and 2 columns
Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device
CUDA kernel launch with 4 blocks of 2 threads
Copy output data from the CUDA device to the host memory
**A** is 0.000000, B is 0.364784, C is 0.364784
**A** is 0.000000, B is 0.952230, C is 0.952230
**A** is 0.000000, B is 0.000000, C is 0.000000
**A** is 0.000000, B is 0.000000, C is 0.000000
**A** is 0.840188, B is 0.394383, C is 1.234571
**A** is 0.783099, B is 0.798440, C is 1.581539
**A** is 0.911647, B is 0.197551, C is 1.109199
**A** is 0.335223, B is 0.768230, C is 1.103452

**Matrix A**

> 0.840188 0.783099
>   0.911647 0.335223
>   0.277775 0.477397
>   0.364784 0.952230

**Matrix B**

> 0.394383 0.798440
>   0.197551 0.768230
>   0.553970 0.628871
>   0.000000 0.000000

**Matrix C**

> 0.0000000.000000
>   0.0000000.000000
>   0.0000000.000000
>   0.0000000.000000

Let me know if you find something wrong with the code.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two coding errors that I found:

1. When you use this method to "bump" the base pointer for matrices `dA` and `dB` in your kernel, you must *also* do the same for the base pointer for matrix `dC`:

   ```
   if ( ind < m ) {
       dA += ind + iby*ldda;
       dB += ind + iby*lddb;
       dC += ind + iby*lddb;  // add this line
   ```
2. Your host-code nested for loops are not indexing correctly.  The outer loop is intended to index across the rows, and you have `n` rows, but you are allowing the outer loop to index across `m` rows:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < n ; j ++)
   ```

   so then when you do the actual indexing calculation here:

   ```
       h_A[i*m+j] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
   ```

   you are indexing out-of-bounds. (`i*m` exceeds the matrix size, for some values of `i`)  This problem is repeated in all of your nested for-loops in host code.  The fix is to reverse the `m`, `n` bounds on your `i`, `j` loops.

The following code has those errors fixed (plus some additions for variable definitions you left out  - `err` and `flag` are undefined in the code you have posted currently -  which create compile errors.) It seems to run correctly and produce the correct result:

```
$ cat t1213.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#define BLK_X 2
#define BLK_Y 1

__global__ void matrixAdd2( const float *dA, const float *dB, float *dC, int m, int n)
{
int ldda = m;
int lddb = m;

int ind = blockIdx.x*BLK_X + threadIdx.x;
int iby = blockIdx.y*BLK_Y;
/* check if full block-column */
bool full = (iby + BLK_Y <= n);
/* do only rows inside matrix */
if ( ind < m ) {
    dA += ind + iby*ldda;
    dB += ind + iby*lddb;
    dC += ind + iby*lddb;
    if ( full )
    {
        // full block-column
        #pragma unroll
        for( int j=0; j < BLK_Y; ++j )
        {
            dC[j*lddb] = dA[j*ldda] + dB[j*lddb];
            printf("A is %f, B is %f, C is %f  \n",dA[j*ldda],dB[j*lddb],dC[j*lddb]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // partial block-column
        for( int j=0; j < BLK_Y && iby+j < n; ++j )
        {
            dC[j*lddb] = dA[j*ldda] + dB[j*lddb];
            printf("parital: A is %f, B is %f, C is %f  \n",dA[j*ldda],dB[j*lddb],dC[j*lddb]);
        }
    }
}
}



int main ( void )
{

int m = 4; // a - mxn matrix
int n = 2; // b - mxn matrix

size_t size =  m * n * sizeof(float);


printf("Matrix addition of %d rows and %d columns \n", m, n);

// allocate matrices on the host

float *h_A = (float *)malloc(size); // a- mxn matrix on the host
float *h_B = (float *)malloc(size); // b- mxn matrix on the host
float *h_C = (float *)malloc(size); // b- mxn matrix on the host


// Initialize the host input matrixs
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m ; j ++)
    {
        h_A[i*m+j] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_B[i*m+j] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;

    }
}

// Allocate the device input matrix A
float *d_A = NULL;
cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, size);; // d_a - mxn matrix a on the device

// Allocate the device input matrix B
float *d_B = NULL;
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, size);

// Allocate the device output matrix C
float *d_C = NULL;
err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, size);

// Copy the host input matrixs A and B in host memory to the device input    matrixs in device memory
printf("Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device\n");
err = cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

err = cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

// defining number of threads and blocks
dim3 threads( BLK_X, BLK_Y );
dim3 grid((int)ceil(m/BLK_X),(int)ceil(n/BLK_Y) );


// Launching kernel
matrixAdd2<<<grid, threads, 0>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, m, n);

// Copy the device result matrix in device memory to the host result matrix in host memory.
printf("Copy output data from the CUDA device to the host memory\n");
err = cudaMemcpy(h_C, d_C, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

//print A matrix
printf("Matrix A");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
   {
        printf(" %f", h_A[i*m+j]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}

// print B matrix if required
printf("Matrix B");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {

        printf(" %f", h_B[i*m+j]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}
int flag = 0;
//Error checkng
printf("Matrix C ");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
   {
        printf("%f", h_C[i*m+j]);
        if(h_C[i*m+j] == h_A[i*m+j] + h_B[i*m+j] )
        {
            flag = flag + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

if(flag==m*n)
{
printf("Test PASSED\n");
}


// Free device global memory
err = cudaFree(d_A);

err = cudaFree(d_B);

err = cudaFree(d_C);

// Free host memory
free(h_A);
free(h_B);
free(h_C);


err = cudaDeviceReset();
printf("Done\n");
return 0;

}
$ nvcc -o t1213 t1213.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1213
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Matrix addition of 4 rows and 2 columns
Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device
Copy output data from the CUDA device to the host memory
A is 0.277775, B is 0.553970, C is 0.831745
A is 0.477397, B is 0.628871, C is 1.106268
A is 0.364784, B is 0.513401, C is 0.878185
A is 0.952230, B is 0.916195, C is 1.868425
A is 0.911647, B is 0.197551, C is 1.109199
A is 0.335223, B is 0.768230, C is 1.103452
A is 0.840188, B is 0.394383, C is 1.234571
A is 0.783099, B is 0.798440, C is 1.581539
Matrix A 0.840188 0.783099 0.911647 0.335223
 0.277775 0.477397 0.364784 0.952230
Matrix B 0.394383 0.798440 0.197551 0.768230
 0.553970 0.628871 0.513401 0.916195
Matrix C 1.2345711.5815391.1091991.103452
0.8317451.1062680.8781851.868425
Test PASSED
Done
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: yeah, that was the problem. thank you for your help :)